# Custom module works on localhost but not on server | Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, server-setup

I have a simple custom module. It works fine on localhost but not on server. Frontend test route get a 404. Backend button action exist but does not works. I have no server log and no magento log. I have try to compile, reindex, flush cache, setting server permission but no way.

Where can i find for a log or try another solution?

Comment: Confirm, you have upload all file or extension with proper permission?

Comment: yes i have upload all file

Comment: Can you try to run setup:upgrade, di:compile and other required commands?

Comment: can you check if that module is enabled in app/etc/config.php ? If it exists and enabled. Then check typo (If you are using local windows machine and Server linux) like case sensitive. The windows might ignore case sensitiveness but not in linux server.

Comment: thanks a lot controller folder changed with Controller. works fine now!